# Could the down/up-voter be given the option of adding a reason?

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface

I've looked at several related threads; some people would like to know why they get downvotes specifically.

I'd like to have the optional ability to state why I'm voting something up or down.

One can optionally explain the reason for her/his edit of a question, so why not the reason for an up or down vote?

A benefit of **SO** is gaining understanding.

Many **SO** members would likely prefer to simply vote up/down... I suspect that others, like myself, would enjoy knowing the reason(s) behind down/up votes.

Design-wise, a simple dropdown could be used to avoid hurtful reasons.

By the way, I'm also willing to have the down/up vote ability to be identified... again, this could be optional. Design example:

> 5 == 7 up (Jeff, Gerry, 5 others); 2 down (unidentified)

This would be useful because a score of 5 might in one case be only 5 up while in another case it could equal 64 up, 59 down.

Comment: You can always leave a comment explaining your vote, and many people  do.  But some don't.

Comment: @Robert Harvey yes, that would be one option; otoh, sometimes the comment may not be very relevant to the actual question so having it here in the comments section may not be the best place for it.

Comment: If they're downvoting the post, the reason is certainly relevant to the post (or it better be), so a comment would be logical

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen true, worth to mention this question was initially closed as duplicate of the other one and has been reopened again by me, as I believe this one here give an explicit way to encourage people, not just discussing it in general. (or asking for any other ways.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Robert said in a comment, if you have enough reputation, you can leave comments on people's posts saying that you either agree or disagree and why (i.e., "+1 <reason>" or "-1 <reason>").

I don't see a need to put in default reasons, nor is there a way to be general about a predefined set of reasons -- it's entirely dependent on context, which varies from site-to-site, question-to-question, and answer-to-answer.

For the case of explaining *downvotes*, search around Meta, as there has been *extensive* discussion about that, so I won't get into it in this answer.

> this would be useful because 5 might in one case be 5 up
>   while in another case it could equal 64 up, 59 down.

This is a [privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts) you can gain at 1,000 rep. Personally-identifiable votes (of most types, including upvotes and downvotes) are confidential, and I highly doubt that's going to change, ever. If people want to identify their own votes *themselves*, that's fine, but there's just *no way* the system will be changed to expose that information by default.

Comment: i've marked this as answer but that does not mean that I'm 100% in agreement ... i do not understand why one needs a 1000 rep to see the up versus down count.  thnx to all who participated.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think that the comments section fulfils this role already (especially in the case of a downvote when you're encouraged to leave a comment if you think the post can be improved.) IMO the comments box is visible enough already that if people want to leave a comment then they will - if they don't I doubt an extra box will really provide much, if any more encouragement.

Answer (score 1):

Letting the voting system remain anonymous encourages a fair voting system.

Also people with low reputation are given a notification to add a comment for their downvote, however doing the same for an upvote doesn't seem to be a requirement. Downvoting is something of an unusual activity whereas upvoting is what you usually do when you feel the post is good enough.

However, it's good practice to leave a comment if you downvote (IMO should be made compulsory so that the poster can improve his/her post based on a comment)... whereas it's up to the voter to comment for an upvote (some usually do it if they like the post `+1`).

As for viewing the original vote count, people with [1000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts) have this ability.

Comment: @Shekar - I disagree with forcing users to leave a comment for downvotes.  Some are quite obvious.  There are a few jacka##es on the sites that just write rude, uncalled for garbage in their comments and answers, and generally these people are looking for a conflict.  I'm not here for that.  If I think the poster can learn something, then I'll leave a comment.  Your answer also contradicts itself.  How can the voting system be anonymous if we're forcing people to leave comments?