# Why is this question upvoted so much?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, up-votes

The question: [permutations and combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543873/permutations-and-combinations)

Why does it have so many upvotes?

- it looks like homework
- it shows no actual work done (the code sample is most likely an example program by the teacher)
- it asks for code

I know it is quite old, but still, not a single downvote!

Comment: And why does this get downvoted? Am I not allowed to ask such questions on meta? Is this question "unclear"? Don't any of you feel strange, that 6/0 votes were cast on this question and that nowadays all almost identical questions are closed immediately?

Comment: [voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Also the linked to question is now in negative votes (!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could the down/up-voter be given the option of adding a reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80884/could-the-down-up-voter-be-given-the-option-of-adding-a-reason)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

6 upvotes is not "so many upvotes".

If I saw over 10/15, then OK possibly I would consider that a lot of upvotes.

And yes, August 2010 is ages ago, when the quality requirements were really much lower (and downvoting a question cost rep, so wasn't done as much as these days). Seeing as it is a basic, old, bad question it most likely doesn't get all that many views, hence no downvotes since.

Comment: This possibly explains no downvotes, but why upvotes? Moreover, currently the community seems to *strongly dislike* such questions. What has changed?

Comment: @Dariusz The community has decided that it doesn't want that kind of question on the site...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist which explains that by now it has 3 downvotes lol

Comment: @Dariusz - The upvotes most probably happened shortly after the question being asked. It got little attention since (until now).

Comment: it now has a score of -1 (!)